# NoSuchMethodError is thrown when I search for the address of Google Maps

Tags: flutter, android-support-library

I am working on an application that has Google Maps in it. When I search for my address, I get an error shown in the image below.

[image: err img]

Is the problem about the app or the Google Maps API? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share more details like your code snippet about error?

Comment: This link is a screenshot of the error 
file:///D:/Downloads/260842712_964224004504357_4031171064090228000_n.jpg

Comment: Sorry but given link is your local link. It is not accessible. We can't help you like that.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J8I7.jpg                                                                                
 Sorry for the mistake in the link, I've put a new link

Comment: Are you using an API key from a project that is linked to a valid billing account?

Comment: yes , Is the problem with the app or from Google Maps?